# Backbone datatypes - type casting?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

It just took me over an hour to find out that a Backbone query on a collection was failing because I queried the wrong data type.
So this query failed because I used the wrong data type for id:

```
element = collection.findWhere({id: "123", att: true});
```

This one worked and returned a model from the collection.

```
element = collection.findWhere({id: 123, att: true});
```

The reason was that I took the id from a DOM element.

I am interfacing a lot with the DOM in my application.
Is there an option in Backbone that would allow me to make it more lenient in regards to data types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to override your models parse method and so a toString on the id coming in. Then you'll have strings from the dom and in your model.

http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse

Personally I'd prefer to explicitly cast my queries instead using parseInt but they're both options